# Hyphen in a verb

Tags: grammar, verbs

We use hyphen to make nouns and adjectives, like: cooking-oil, 13-year-old, over-grown etc. But, can we use a hyphen to make a verb, like: ’post-process’, ‘re-purchase’? 
I’m writing sentences with them below to clarify.

1. Does screen size matter to ’post-process’ photos and videos?
2. Your items have been ‘re-purchased’.

Answer (score 1):

There are no nouns in your examples, only *prefixes*. Sometimes prefixes are hyphenated, sometimes not.

"[Repurchase](https://www.lexico.com/definition/repurchase)" *is* a word, so you can use that without a hyphen. Most words with the "re" prefix are not hyphenated (eg *regain, rejoin, remarry* etc).

"Post-process" seems to be a perfectly acceptable verb. It isn't the hyphen that makes it a verb, nor is "post" a noun in this example - it is a prefix derived from a preposition. Don't confuse it with unrelated noun definitions of "post" such as mail, job roles, fence-posts etc.

Some nouns *can* become verbs though - this is known as [verbing](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-verbing/). An example of this is the noun "table" which is sometimes used as a verb, eg "*let's table this for now*".